# What should we name the Halo 5: Guardians tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

*Halo 5: Guardians* was launched 3 days ago, on 27th October, 2015.

[image: Halo 5: Guardians header/poster]

We already have a tag for it: [halo-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-5), which (at the time of writing)  has 12 questions.

According to the [official site](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-au/games/halo-5-guardians) and the [Microsoft XBOX site](http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/games/halo-5-guardians), its official full name is **Halo 5: Guardians**. It is written with its full name in both of the website addresses, and all the websites on the first page of a [Google search for Halo 5](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=halo%205&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=yTAzVt3_O8PUmAWq2aTgCQ) also refer to it as Halo 5: Guardians.

AFAIK, our current policy <sup>[citation needed]</sup> for game tags is to use the full official game name where possible, and propose common names as synonyms. According to this policy, the tag should be named [halo-5-guardians](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-5-guardians).

So, **should we rename [halo-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-5) to [halo-5-guardians](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-5-guardians),** and make the first a synonym of the second, **or keep it the way it is**?

Comment: If someone can find the relevant meta discussion for that game tag naming policy, please feel free to edit it in

Comment: If no relevant meta is brought forward, in terms of supporting either the simply numerals convention, or including the full name, might I propose changing this to concern all games with the same issue, with halo 5 as our primary case example? My understanding is that we only shorten the name when it is required to fit within the character limit, but I have seen a few "shortened name" tags, that this discussion would apply to just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag merged and synonym created as per request.